# Привести изображения к одному цветовому фону

Tags: изображения

Нужно различные изображения (в основном иконоки для кнопок и панелей) привести к одному общему цветовому стилю.

Т.е. имею иконки в различных цветовых тонах и нужно сделать из них изображения с одним одинаковым заданным цветовым тоном (официальным цветом фирмы).

Как это можно сделать, например при помощи GIMPa?

Comment: Вопрос, скорее всего, не по теме сайта. А в качестве решения же, можете сделать так: 1) обесцвечиваете все изображения; 2) заново раскрашиваете их в необходимые цвета.

Comment: Я не силен в графических программах, буду рад пошаговой инструкции

Answer (score 1):

*Раз вы задаете вопрос здесь, то вот вам алгоритм, для реализации на любом языке программирования:*

1. Получить список картинок. Далее по списку
2. Смотрим каждую картинку
3. Переводим в цветовое пространство HSB или HSV (в нем коррекция тона проще)
4. Вычисляем средний тон изображения
5. Сравниваем с образцовым тоном, получаем разницу
6. Приводим картинку к образцовому тону, применяя коррекцию разницы
7. Переводим обратно в RGB
8. Сохраняем и переходим к следующей картинке.

Если у вас будут вопросы по конкретным шагам - задавайте новые уточняющие вопросы!